# killing the master process spawned by an at command

Tags: bash, notify-osd

Using `at`, I'm trying to set up a command that sends me a reminder at a specific time, and keeps reminding me over and over.     But I want to be able to kill the `at` command once I've reminded myself.    However I can't find the PID for the `at` command that I need in order to kill the reminder.    The script I'm running is

> at $thisTime -f $thisFile

where $thisFile looks somthing like this

```
#!/bin/bash
sleepTime=20
while [ 1 > 0 ];
    do
        notify-send "word"
        sleep $sleepTime
    done
```

The command works fine, but it continues to run the `notify-osd` command at the specified intervals, forever.

When I run `ps auxw` I would expect to be find a line identifying the `at` command that I ran to generate this reminder, but nothing comes up.

I've also tried running `atq`  and them `atrm` to remove the numbers that `atq` returned, but I still can't kill the master command, and continue to get `notify-send` messages until I log out.

Could somebody please tell me how I can find the pid for the `at` command?  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The at command will terminate as soon you create the "at" job. The job is initiated by the at daemon (atd), which you dont want to kill or it wont spawn anything else.

You actually want to kill the bash process running $thisFile (search for bash $thisFile in the ps output)

You could also modify the script to include its PID in the message it sends: `notify-send "$$: word"`, so you know which process to kill straight away

Comment: I couldn't find the bash process running $thisFile, but adding `$$` to the message gave me exactly what I needed, thanks!